# Android webView and Javascript interaction

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm working with an activity with a `WebView` embedded in it.
Now i want to display some content:

```
WebView mweb = new WebView(this);  
mweb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
setContentView(mweb);  
......   
mweb.loadData(tot, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

`String tot` is the html text i like to render in the mweb, wich is composed of the `div` tag with an 'ondblclick' event like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = "false";
        function changeHighlight(myElement) {
            if(test == "false"){
               document.getElementById(myElement).className = 'highlight';
               test = "true";
            }else{
               document.getElementById(myElement).className = 'default';
               test = "false";
            }
        }
    </script>    
    <body>
         <div id="center" ondblclick="javascript:changeHighlight('center');">Select here!!!</div>
    </body>
```

How i can trigger this event with JavaScript inside the WebView to select div and to highlight it ?
All is ok with 'onclick' event but not with 'ondblclick'.

Then how i can prompt the user to choose if the `div` tag is selected or not?
Is it possible to insert a confirm dialog ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Sorry for my english.......thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked, but have a look at [this article](http://mscerts.programming4.us/programming/coding%20javascript%20for%20mobile%20browsers%20%28part%2010%29%20-%20event%20handling.aspx). Hope this can still help you.